# Interesting output in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, complex

I found interesting behaviour, best illustrated in the following example. When trying to evaluate

```
Integrate[1/(d^2 - 1), d]
```

Mathematica 11.3 gives the following output:

```
1/2 Log[1 - d] - 1/2 Log[1 + d]
```

It's the right answer for the case when $d<1$. However, suppose that $d>1$. Then the output shall be equal to

```
1/2 Log[d - 1] - 1/2 Log[1 + d]
```

These outputs' difference is $\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\ln(d-1)-\ln(e^{i\pi}(d-1))\Bigr)=\frac{1}{2}(-i\pi+2\pi k)\neq0$.

It's possible to track these differences in later calculations or use definite integration

```
Assuming[t1 > 1 && t2 > t1, Integrate[1/(d^2 - 1), {d, t1, t2}]],
```

but maybe there's a way to deal with it in the case of indefinite integral (or I'm missing something trivial)?

Comment: Indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant. So these two results are exactly equivalent, there is no problem. The value of the constant can depend on the method; but you can also add further constants if you like, to make the results match.

Comment: @Roman yes, that's so dumb of me: I just thought that integration constant shall be real.. If you post your comment as answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it comes from a misunderstanding of the mathematical concept of an indefinite integral, and has nothing to do with Mathematica.

Comment: @Roman maybe I shall just delete it?

Comment: Maybe leave it so other people can find it when they search for a similar issue.

Comment: `Integrate[1/(d^2 - 1), d, GeneratedParameters -> C]` where the parameter can be complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant. So these two results are exactly equivalent, there is no problem. The value of the constant can depend on the method; but you can also add further constants if you like, to make the results match.